# What are the formatter parameters in behat.yml?

Tags: behat

[The formatter section in this guide on configurations](http://behat.readthedocs.org/en/v2.5/guides/7.config.html#formatter) gives an example of formatter parameters, but doesn't explain them:

```
# behat.yml
default:
    formatter:
        name:                       pretty
        parameters:
            decorated:              true
            verbose:                false
            time:                   true
            language:               en
            output_path:            null
            multiline_arguments:    true
            #...
```

There is no explanation for what `verbose` or `decorated` does, I have tried setting to `true` and `false` but it seemed to make no difference. Also I was wondering if there are any other parameters which aren't in that example.

Can anyone please explain what these parameters do?

Answer (score 0):

A quote from the link you provided:

> The `parameters` section defines additional parameters which will be provided into the formatter instance. **As you can see, all parameters from this section duplicate `behat` tool options.** You can redefine `behat` formatter defaults here. Also, this is the place to specify parameters for your custom formatters.

The `behat` tool options are explained when running `behat --help`.